# Fragment is not scrollable

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I am trying to make my whole fragment scrollable vertically. I have implemented a horizontal scrollview and it works fine. The following is my xml file. I have tried implementing scrollview for the whole fragment but I get an error stating scrollview can only host one direct child. I am new to java so detailed answers would help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_explore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.explore.ExploreFragment">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="406dp"
        android:layout_height="217dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.108">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="217dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:columnCount="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowCount="2"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/but1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:onClick="deviceList" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_apple" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_logitech" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_razer" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_samsung" />


        </GridLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="412dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.996">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:columnCount="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:rowCount="4">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_mp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_mp"  />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_samsung" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_samsung" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_mp"  />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_samsung" />


            </GridLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you need multiple scroll views, use NestedScrollView.

I modified your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_explore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/but1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:columnCount="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:rowCount="8">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle_red" />


            </GridLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

it make both scrollviews move smooth.

and please Do not use fixed size except when you really need. check this.

Comment: i see, i think you missed out the following line at the end: </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>